# YouTube Iframe API - Play video on mobile

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

After searching and finding many similar questions, I can't find the correct answer. So I'm working with the YouTube Iframe API, and I know that autoplay etc. won't work for mobiles. And I have created a **element** that displays on mobiles, so when the user click that button, it should play the video. But I only get this message: *"Try restarting your device if playback does not start soon"*.

```
var playElement = document.createElement("div");
playElement.style.display = "none";

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
   playElement.style.display = "block";
}

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   player = new YT.Player(child, {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      videoId: youtubeID,
      playerVars: {
         'iv_load_policy': 3,
         'enablejsapi': 1,
         'disablekb': 1,
         'autoplay': 1,
         'loop': 0,
         'controls': 0,
         'showinfo': 0,
         'rel': 0,
         'mode': 'transparent'
      },
      events: {
         'onReady': onPlayerReady,
         'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
   });
}

playElement.onclick = function() {
   player.playVideo();;
};
```

Anyone that does have an actual working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remember player refers to a div with the ID 'player'. You can start with the example code on [youtube api doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). It will autoplay when the video has loaded. You can add your playerVar options as well.

A note for mobile video autoplay. You can have it autoplay but it has to be muted. So you can try adding `player.mute()` when you it loads and setup a click handler to unmute it again if that is what you prefer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          },
          playerVars
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```